# Flume Spark Streaming into Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, flume

I have Spark Single node and I'm going to stream data into mysql using Apache **Flume -> Spark -> Mysql**,
I used **foreachPartition** method but data insertion is getting slow and there is a queue in Spark UI.

Is there any suggestion to improve this data insertion. I need to process 3000 rows per second.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] - we don't even know if "slow" means 3 rows per second, 30, 300 or 2900, or what you do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the configuration details for your query.
Are you using the bulkimport for mysql.